# AEM replicator skip cq:lastReplicatedBy changing on publisher

Tags: aem

I am using Replicator API to publish multiple pages and I want to know if there is an option to force the replicator to skip changing page parameters like **cq:lastReplicatedBy** since we are using a system user and I assume that when the replication occur this page parameter will be updated with **admin** value or whatever user is used by replicator.

Comment: What is the goal? If the system user did it, it will appear that it was last replicated by that system user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I implemented was to retrieve the value before replicator is triggering the process (as a backup) and after that to reinitialize the changed value with the backup. I tought that there might be an option on Replicator API but I didn't found it.

Solution sample:

```
try {
    ModifiableValueMap properties = resource.adaptTo(ModifiableValueMap.class)
    String backupValue = properties.get("cq:lastReplicatedBy");
    
    replicator.replicate(session, replicationActionType, path);
    
    properties.put("cq:lastReplicatedBy", backupValue);
    resourceResolver.commit();
} catch(PersistenceException | ReplicationException e) { }
```